# CakePHP : override BasicAuthenticate.php

Tags: cakephp, overriding, basic-authentication

I'm trying to override **lib/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/BasicAuthenticate.php**, 
because I need to change the unauthenticated() method.

So I copied and modified the file to **app/Lib/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/BasicAuthenticate.php** (also tried without the '*Cake*' folder), but the changes are not taken into account.

My edit works when modifying directly the core file but I'd rather not.

How should I do ?
I'm using Cake 2.5

Comment: Are you sure that you need to _exchange_ the class, ie are there adapters in use that extend or use `BasicAuthenticate` and need to use a modified `unauthenticated()` method? Because if not, then you're plan is wrong from the beginning.

Comment: Not sure of what you try to point out, but actually I need to prevent the WWW-Authenticate header from being sent to an unauthenticated access attempt. This is why I thought I'd just remove this line from the method :
    $Exception->responseHeader(array($this->loginHeaders()));

Comment: Let me ask it this way, is the basic authentication handler the only authentication handler that you are using throughout your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Check if you really need to override a core class

To me this looks like you are on the wrong track, overriding the class shouldn't be neccesary unless for example you have no controler over where and how the basic authentication adapter is being used (for example in a plugin that doesn't offer configuration).

If you'd really need to overwrite the class, then the path should be

**app/Lib/Controller/Component/Auth/BasicAuthenticate.php**

and it should work just fine (it does for me, using CakePHP 2.5.6).

**http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#overriding-classes-in-cakephp**

---

## Use a custom authentication handler instead

If you have control over the adapter configuration, the I'd suggest that you *extend* the `BasicAuthenticate` class instead, and only override the `unauthenticate()` method, and finally make the auth component use the custom adapter.

Something like

**app/Controller/Component/Auth/CustomBasicAuthenticate.php**

```
App::uses('BasicAuthenticate', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class CustomBasicAuthenticate extends BasicAuthenticate {
    public function unauthenticated(CakeRequest $request, CakeResponse $response) {
        // do something special
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'CustomBasic'
        )
    )
);
```

See also the [**Creating Custom Authentication objects**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authentication-objects) section in the Cookbook.